# JavaFX GridPane Changing Visibility of Specific Lines

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder, gridpane

I'm working on a JavaFX Sudoku game with a 9x9 GridPane as my board and I want to make the grid lines visible only around the boxes so every 3 rows and columns however I haven't been able to find any working solutions yet.

grid.setGridLinesVisible(true) only has the option to make every line visible

I also tried adding the statement gridLinesVisible="true" in the fxml code for the specific column and row constraints but it wouldn't allow me to put that in.

Any other ideas? Thank you :D

Comment: You should not be using `grid.setGrildLinesVisible(true);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using one `GridPane` for the entire layout, I suggest using 10 separate `GridPane` containers: 9 for the individual sections and 1 to hold them all.

Here's a simple FXML layout to demonstrate (borders included):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<VBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <children>
        <GridPane gridLinesVisible="true" style="-fx-border-color: black; -fx-border-width: 3;">
            <columnConstraints>
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="150.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="150.0"/>
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="150.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="150.0"/>
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="150.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="150.0"/>
            </columnConstraints>
            <rowConstraints>
                <RowConstraints maxHeight="150.0" minHeight="150.0" prefHeight="150.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                <RowConstraints maxHeight="150.0" minHeight="150.0" prefHeight="150.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                <RowConstraints maxHeight="150.0" minHeight="150.0" prefHeight="150.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
            </rowConstraints>
            <children>
                <GridPane gridLinesVisible="true">
                    <columnConstraints>
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="50.0" minWidth="50.0" prefWidth="50.0"/>
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="50.0" minWidth="50.0" prefWidth="50.0"/>
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="50.0" minWidth="50.0" prefWidth="50.0"/>
                    </columnConstraints>
                    <rowConstraints>
                        <RowConstraints maxHeight="50.0" minHeight="50.0" prefHeight="50.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                        <RowConstraints maxHeight="50.0" minHeight="50.0" prefHeight="50.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                        <RowConstraints maxHeight="50.0" minHeight="50.0" prefHeight="50.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                    </rowConstraints>
                </GridPane>
                <GridPane gridLinesVisible="true" GridPane.columnIndex="1">
                    <columnConstraints>
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="50.0" minWidth="50.0" prefWidth="50.0"/>
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="50.0" minWidth="50.0" prefWidth="50.0"/>
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="50.0" minWidth="50.0" prefWidth="50.0"/>
                    </columnConstraints>
                    <rowConstraints>
                        <RowConstraints maxHeight="50.0" minHeight="50.0" prefHeight="50.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                        <RowConstraints maxHeight="50.0" minHeight="50.0" prefHeight="50.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                        <RowConstraints maxHeight="50.0" minHeight="50.0" prefHeight="50.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                    </rowConstraints>
                </GridPane>
                <GridPane gridLinesVisible="true" GridPane.columnIndex="2">
                    <columnConstraints>
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="50.0" minWidth="50.0" prefWidth="50.0"/>
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="50.0" minWidth="50.0" prefWidth="50.0"/>
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="50.0" minWidth="50.0" prefWidth="50.0"/>
                    </columnConstraints>
                    <rowConstraints>
                        <RowConstraints maxHeight="50.0" minHeight="50.0" prefHeight="50.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                        <RowConstraints maxHeight="50.0" minHeight="50.0" prefHeight="50.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                        <RowConstraints maxHeight="50.0" minHeight="50.0" prefHeight="50.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                    </rowConstraints>
                </GridPane>
                <GridPane gridLinesVisible="true" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                    <columnConstraints>
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="50.0" minWidth="50.0" prefWidth="50.0"/>
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="50.0" minWidth="50.0" prefWidth="50.0"/>
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="50.0" minWidth="50.0" prefWidth="50.0"/>
                    </columnConstraints>
                    <rowConstraints>
                        <RowConstraints maxHeight="50.0" minHeight="50.0" prefHeight="50.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                        <RowConstraints maxHeight="50.0" minHeight="50.0" prefHeight="50.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                        <RowConstraints maxHeight="50.0" minHeight="50.0" prefHeight="50.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                    </rowConstraints>
                </GridPane>
                <GridPane gridLinesVisible="true" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                    <columnConstraints>
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="50.0" minWidth="50.0" prefWidth="50.0"/>
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="50.0" minWidth="50.0" prefWidth="50.0"/>
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="50.0" minWidth="50.0" prefWidth="50.0"/>
                    </columnConstraints>
                    <rowConstraints>
                        <RowConstraints maxHeight="50.0" minHeight="50.0" prefHeight="50.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                        <RowConstraints maxHeight="50.0" minHeight="50.0" prefHeight="50.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                        <RowConstraints maxHeight="50.0" minHeight="50.0" prefHeight="50.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                    </rowConstraints>
                </GridPane>
                <GridPane gridLinesVisible="true" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                    <columnConstraints>
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="50.0" minWidth="50.0" prefWidth="50.0"/>
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="50.0" minWidth="50.0" prefWidth="50.0"/>
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="50.0" minWidth="50.0" prefWidth="50.0"/>
                    </columnConstraints>
                    <rowConstraints>
                        <RowConstraints maxHeight="50.0" minHeight="50.0" prefHeight="50.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                        <RowConstraints maxHeight="50.0" minHeight="50.0" prefHeight="50.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                        <RowConstraints maxHeight="50.0" minHeight="50.0" prefHeight="50.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                    </rowConstraints>
                </GridPane>
                <GridPane gridLinesVisible="true" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
                    <columnConstraints>
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="50.0" minWidth="50.0" prefWidth="50.0"/>
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="50.0" minWidth="50.0" prefWidth="50.0"/>
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="50.0" minWidth="50.0" prefWidth="50.0"/>
                    </columnConstraints>
                    <rowConstraints>
                        <RowConstraints maxHeight="50.0" minHeight="50.0" prefHeight="50.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                        <RowConstraints maxHeight="50.0" minHeight="50.0" prefHeight="50.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                        <RowConstraints maxHeight="50.0" minHeight="50.0" prefHeight="50.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                    </rowConstraints>
                </GridPane>
                <GridPane gridLinesVisible="true" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
                    <columnConstraints>
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="50.0" minWidth="50.0" prefWidth="50.0"/>
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="50.0" minWidth="50.0" prefWidth="50.0"/>
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="50.0" minWidth="50.0" prefWidth="50.0"/>
                    </columnConstraints>
                    <rowConstraints>
                        <RowConstraints maxHeight="50.0" minHeight="50.0" prefHeight="50.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                        <RowConstraints maxHeight="50.0" minHeight="50.0" prefHeight="50.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                        <RowConstraints maxHeight="50.0" minHeight="50.0" prefHeight="50.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                    </rowConstraints>
                </GridPane>
                <GridPane gridLinesVisible="true" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
                    <columnConstraints>
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="50.0" minWidth="50.0" prefWidth="50.0"/>
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="50.0" minWidth="50.0" prefWidth="50.0"/>
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="50.0" minWidth="50.0" prefWidth="50.0"/>
                    </columnConstraints>
                    <rowConstraints>
                        <RowConstraints maxHeight="50.0" minHeight="50.0" prefHeight="50.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                        <RowConstraints maxHeight="50.0" minHeight="50.0" prefHeight="50.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                        <RowConstraints maxHeight="50.0" minHeight="50.0" prefHeight="50.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                    </rowConstraints>
                </GridPane>
            </children>
        </GridPane>
    </children>
    <padding>
        <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0"/>
    </padding>
</VBox>
```

So here I have one 3x3 `GridPane` where each cell is 150x150 pixels. Within each of those 9 cells, I have added another 3x3 `GridPane` whose cells are each 50x50.

This creates a uniform Sudoku grid, ready for use:

[image: Screenshot]